# fgetcsv vs explode to target specific columns in a delimited text table

Tags: php, html, arrays, flat-file

I have been reading how to target certain columns to be in array but am confused on what technique is best between explode and fgetcsv.

I already started down the road with fgetcsv, and it works for echos but when I create my table it all falls apart...

here's a small part of database... For example say I want column's 1-4 from all the HDR index's...

```
RAK 0 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; grey ; grey 
RAK 1 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; grey ; grey 
RAK 2 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; red ; red 
RAK 3 ; none ; ACU; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; red ; red 
HDR 0 ; 1    ; 2   ; 3   ;  4  ; 5   ; 6   ; 7
HDR 1 ; 1a    ; 2a   ; 3a   ;  4a  ; 5a   ; 6a   ; 7a**
```

This is the variable I came up with, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("jobstatus2.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo '<table border="0">';

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

 echo '</tbody></table>';
 fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

It almost does but a miss is as good as a mile. How can I include column's 1-4 with fgetcsv or do I need to use the explode function?

This is the variable I've been using to get any specific record but it doesn't work with arrays.

```
<?php

$statusled = array();
if (($handle = fopen("status.txt", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
{
    if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'BRD')
    {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $status = $data[1];
        $statusled[ $board ] = $status;
    }
    }
     fclose($handle);
  }
 ?>
```

Thanks,

William

Comment: you don't "include" columns, with fgetcsv. if the line read from the line parses, then every field in that line gets pulled apart and stuffed into the array that fgetcsv returns. you need to do basic debuggin: `var_dump($data)` to see if you're reading the lines properly in the first place.

Comment: what does the output look like? Can you make sure that your csv is formatted correctly? You can definitely use explode. You just have to read the file line by line. You just got to make sure that the delimiter is not present in the data

Comment: Marc, thank you, that helped me out a lot. . Khuderm, thank you as well, I appreciate your help.

Comment: So I thought I would show what I came up with so it might help someone else...

Comment: So I thought I would show what I came up with so it might help someone else... i added this after the while statement if ($row > 1 && substr($data[0],0,3) != 'JOB' ) continue; and it works with regards to going to all rows that start with JOB and with regards to columns if I change $c=0 to $c=1 then it starts at the second column... How would I include a range of columns here. I was hoping it would be as simple as $c=1-3 but that doesn't work.